# All Methods Not Covered in Test Class

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

My test class runs with no error, but unfortunately, not all methods are covered. Only the `addNewRow()` method is covered.

**Controller:**

```
public with sharing class MyController {

    private ApexPages.StandardController parentController;
    public Parent__c parent {get;set;}
    public List<MyWrapper> wraplist {get;set;} 
    public Integer rowToRemove {get;set;}
    public String selected {get; set;}
    public Boolean form1 {get; set;}
    public Boolean form2 {get; set;} 

    public MyController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        parentController = controller;
        this.parent = (Parent__c)controller.getRecord();

        form1 = form2 = false;
        selected = '';

        wraplist = new List<MyWrapper>();
        addNewRow();


    }

    public void addNewRow() {
        List<MyWrapper> temp_list = new List<MyWrapper>();
        MyWrapper newRecord = new MyWrapper();
        Child__c newChildRecord = new Child__c();
        newRecord.ch = newChildRecord;
        newRecord.index = temp_list.size();
        temp_list.add(newRecord);    
        for(MyWrapper wloop : temp_list) {
            wraplist.add(wloop);
        }
    }

    public void removeRow() {
        List<MyWrapper> rem_list = new List<MyWrapper>();
        for(MyWrapper wloop : wraplist) {
            rem_list.add(wloop);
        }
        rem_list.remove(rowToRemove);
        wraplist.clear();
        for(MyWrapper rloop : rem_list) {
            wraplist.add(rloop);
        }
    }

    Public PageReference cancel() {

        PageReference pageref = new PageReference('/home/home.jsp');
        pageref.setRedirect(true);
        return pageref;
    }

    public PageReference save() {

        List<MyWrapper> childlist = new List<MyWrapper>();
        List<Child__c > newChildList = new List<Child__c >();
        Decimal total = 0;
        for(MyWrapper wloop : wraplist) {
            childlist.add(wloop);
        }

        for(MyWrapper tloop : childlist) {
            total += tloop.ch.Amount__c;

        }

        Parent__c p1 = new Parent__c();
        p1.Account__c = parent.Account__c;

        p1.Total__c = total;
        insert p1;

        if(childlist !=null && !childlist.isEmpty()) {

            for(MyWrapper rec : childlist) {
                Child__c chTemp = new Child__c ();
                chTemp.Amount__c = rec.ch.Amount__c;
                chTemp.Date__c = rec.ch.Date__c;
        chTemp.Child_Name_Type__c = rec.ch.Child_Name_Type__c;


                chTemp.Parent__c = p1.id;
                newChildList.add(chTemp);

            }
        }

        if(newChildList.size() > 0) {
            insert newChildList;
        }

        PageReference pageref = new PageReference('/' + p1  .Id);
        pageref.setRedirect(true);
        return pageref;
    }


    public void onChangeValue(){

        if(selected == 'A'){
            form1 = true;
            form2 = false;
        }

        else if(selected == 'B'){
            form1 = false;
            form2 = true;
        }

        else{
            form1 = false;
            form2 = false;
        }
    } 

   public class MyWrapper {

        public Integer index {get;set;}
        public Child__c ch {get;set;}

    }

}
```

**Test Class:**

```
@isTest
public class MyTestClass {
    private static testMethod void insertRecord() {
        Schema.DescribeSObjectResult sch = Schema.SObjectType.Parent__c;
        Map<String,Schema.RecordTypeInfo> ParentRecordTypeInfo = sch.getRecordTypeInfosByName();

        Id rtId = ParentRecordTypeInfo.get('B').getRecordTypeId();

        Parent__c p = new Parent__c();
        p.RecordTypeId = ParentRecordTypeInfo.get('B').getRecordTypeId();
        insert p;

        List<Child__c> childList = new List<Child__c>();
        for(Integer i=0; i<200; i++) {
            Child__c c = new Child__c();
            c.Child_Name_Type__c = 'B1';
            c.Date__c = Date.parse('1/1/2016');
            c.Amount__c = 1000.00;
            childlist.add(c);
        }
        insert childList;

        Test.startTest();

        ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.StandardController(p);
        MyController mc = new MyController(sc);
        mc.save();
        PageReference pg = Page.MyPage;
        Test.setCurrentPage(pg);

        Test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In your test class, only the method named **addNewRow()** is invoked.
In order to cover other methods, you have to invoke them.
The methods need to be invoked are

**removeRow()** , **cancel()** , **save()** and **onChangeValue()**.

Answer (score 3):

Junaid is correct that you must invoke all the methods you have written, and some of them multiple times in order to hit all the execution paths. But more importantly, you should focus on adding assertions. Right now, you are merely [smoke testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoke_testing#Smoke_testing_in_software_development), which is not nearly as helpful to future developers. Remember, that may include yourself.

Take a look at [An Introduction to Apex Code Test Methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Apex_Code_Test_Methods):

> - Use `System.assert` methods to prove that code behaves properly.
>
> This is key to ensure that the Apex code executes to the expected value or behavior. This will also facilitate regression testing as the Apex code changes over time.

And also check out [How to Write Good Unit Tests](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/How_to_Write_Good_Unit_Tests) (emphasis mine):

> #### Verify the results are correct
>
> **Verifying that your code works as you expect it to work is the most important part of unit testing**. It’s also one of the things that Force.com developers commonly neglect. Unit tests that do not verify the results of the code aren’t true unit tests. They are commonly referred to as [smoke tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoke_testing#Smoke_testing_in_software_development), which **aren’t nearly as effective or informative as true unit tests**.
>
> A good way to tell if unit tests are properly verifying results is to look for liberal use of the `System.assert()` methods. If there aren’t any `System.assert()` method calls, then the tests aren’t verifying results properly. And, no, `System.assert(true);` doesn’t count.
>
> Sample verification code for this trigger might look like this:
>
> ```
> a = [SELECT Name, Most_Recently_Created_Opportunity_Name__c
>      FROM Account
>      WHERE Id = :a.Id];
>
> System.assertEquals('My Opportunity', a.Most_Recently_Created_Opportunity_Name__c);
> ```
>
> Notice that this unit testing code explicitly verifies that the trigger performed the action that we expected.

Answer (score 0):

For more test coverage, you have to call every method by making an instance of MyController.

```
MyController myController = new MyController();
```

Example :

```
myController.removeRow();
myController.save();
```

Also, u have to initialise the public variable that is used in the method of the controller.

Example :

```
myController.rowToRemove = 5;
myController.form1 = true ;
myController.form2 = true ;
```

Comment: How can I do this inside my testMethods? Forgive me for asking but I'm really not sure if I'm doing it right on the code I've posted.

Comment: @curdual yes, u r doing correct.

Comment: Inside ur test method , just add the following code . 

MyController myController = new MyController();
myController.removeRow(); 
myController.save(); myController.cancel();myController.onChangeValue